# Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it

Tags: python, python-requests

When making a GET request to

```
https://apicache.vudu.com/api2/?_type=contentSearch&contentEncoding=gzip&contentId={}&dimensionality=any&followup=ultraVioletability&followup=longCredits&followup=superType&followup=episodeNumberInSeason&followup=advertContentDefinitions&followup=tag&followup=hasBonusWithTagExtras&followup=subtitleTrack&followup=ratingsSummaries&followup=geneGenres&followup=seasonNumber&followup=trailerEditionId&followup=genres&followup=usefulStreamableOffers&followup=walmartOffers&followup=preOrderOffers&followup=editions&followup=merchandiseContentMaps&followup=promoTags&followup=advertEnabled&format=application%2Fjson
```

**from AWS**, I intermittently receive the following error:

```
ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check',))
```

Example:

```
requests.get(url.format('832504'))
<Response [200]>
requests.get(url.format('460398'))
<Response [200]>
requests.get(url.format('27616'))
<Response [200]>
requests.get(url.format('23657'))
<Response [200]>
requests.get(url.format('8661'))
ContentDecodingError...
requests.get(url.format('14250'))
<Response [200]>
requests.get(url.format('516307'))
ContentDecodingError...
requests.get(url.format('10366'))
<Response [200]>
```

I have tried different combinations of headers (including the suggestion here: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3849) and removing the `contentEncoding=gzip` param (which returns 502 status code).

Considering this API works flawlessly on my PC, perhaps there is some conflict between Vudu and AWS?

Comment: Can you try with other `Content-Type`. `gzip, compress, identity, deflate, br`

Comment: I'm assuming you meant Accept-Encoding and yes I have tried them.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having it too.

Comment: It's been a while and, ironically, I'm unable to reproduce this. Can you try setting the verify param to False?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is current python requests library limitation (or design behavior, see [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1586))

So you have to use `resp.raw` to get the raw bytes.  (**Note**: to access `resp.raw`, it also requires `stream=True`).

```
resp = session.get(url, stream=True)
data = resp.raw.read()
```